# UDP packets can't be received by client on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking, udp

I've tried to make an UDP client that can run on a WP7 device, communicating via a wifi network. I've used this example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202864(v=vs.105).aspx . Sending messages to the server works, but the reply sent out by the server never makes it back to the phone. I always get a timeout.

I'm a 100% sure that the server is working correctly. I've built a regular c# client application that was able to receive the messages from the server. I had to build that application  in Release mode to get it working, but that trick did not work for the WP7 version.

Comment: Are you running the phone on WiFi for testing so it's not a block by your phone operator?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, it's all wifi. The whole setup is intented only for wifi.